# python function combining values

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to create a full card deck (52 cards) and later on shuffle randomly the card deck.

I wrote the following function, but unfortunately it returns only 16 values of "Hearts".

How should I change the code?

```
def get_deck():
suit = ["Hearts", "Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds"]
value = ["Ace", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
a =[]

for color in suit:
    for number in value:
        i = color + " " + str(number)
        a.append(i)
    return a
```

`get_deck()`

```
['Hearts Ace', 'Hearts 2', 'Hearts 3', 'Hearts 4', 'Hearts 5', 'Hearts 6', 'Hearts 7', 'Hearts 8', 'Hearts 9', 'Hearts 10', 'Hearts Jack', 'Hearts Queen', 'Hearts King']
```

Comment: de-dent the return statement one level. you are exiting the for loop(s) too early.

Answer (score 2):

Your return indent should be out of the for loop

```
def get_deck():
    suit = ["Hearts", "Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds"]
    value = ["Ace", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
    a =[]

    for color in suit:
        for number in value:
            i = color + " " + str(number)
            a.append(i)
    return a
print get_deck()
```